# Codeception Content-disposition assert file

Tags: codeception

I want to assert a xls file. I get this back:

```
"attachment; filename="testify.xlsx""
```

How can I do assertions on the file?

I have the tmp Path from the `$_SERVER['TMPDIR']` and a clean filename, but there is no file in directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in methods for this purpose, you will have to write your own [helper](http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#Helpers).

If you are using PhpBrowser or one of framework modules, they have two useful hidden methods:
[_getResponseContent](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#_getResponseContent) returns page(or file) content,
[_savePageSource](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#_savePageSource) saves it to file.

So your helper method would look like this:

```
function seeXlsFileIsValid()
{
    $fileContent = $this->getModule('PhpBrowser)->_getResponseContent();
    $this->assertTrue(..., 'returned xls file is not valid');
}
```

If you want to assert response headers, copy seeHttpHeader method from [REST module](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.1.8/src/Codeception/Module/REST.php#L171).

Comment: only returns empty sting on $this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->_getResponseContent()...any other idea?

Comment: Also $this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->_savePageSource(codecept_output_dir().'page.html');
is making en empty page

Comment: Yes but you also must use this setting in php browser

curl:
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true

Comment: No you mustn't. I have tried to reproduce your issue, but _getResponseContent() returns string in all cases. Should you tell me about other unusual parameters that you are using in your tests?

Answer (score 0):

codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
    shuffle: true
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
coverage:
  enabled: true
  c3_url: 'http://www-dev.testify.com:8080/c3.php'
  remote: false
  whitelist:
      include:
          - _php/*
```

api.suite.yml

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://www-dev.testify.com:8080
            clear_cookies: false
            restart: false
            curl:
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
        - REST:
            url: http://www-dev.testify.com:8080
            depends: PhpBrowser
            part: Json
        - Asserts
        - Helper\Api
        - Db:
            dsn: 'sqlite:tests/_output/database.sqlite'
            user: ''
            password: ''
env:
    fast:
```